# Is it possible to set card details(number, date, cvc) on Stripe checkout form fields dynamically(via variables) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, checkout

I just wanted to set Card details on Stripe checkout form using a Swipe-card-reader so that a User can do the payments through the reader without typing those Card details. Please just clarify me is it possible or not. if it possible, what is the criteria behind it?

Comment: The only way to process a card swipe/dip with Stripe is via [Terminal](https://stripe.com/terminal).

Comment: Thanks @taintedzodiac  I found it has been mentioned in stripe that no access for sensitive information. If I summarize my attempt, I only able focus on certain field through mounting element!